# What is the difference between exec inside the shell and exec directly the command?

Tags: c

I am writing a generic library function which uses exec, I want to know what difference
does it make by using something like
`execl(<command abs path>, command, (char *) NULL);` directly 
( `ex. execl("/usr/bin/ls", "ls", (char *) NULL);` )
instead of -

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) NULL);
```

i.e., how does it help by executing inside the shell. I have seen most of
the references (books and online) executing inside the shell, why ?

Answer (score 4):

**Directly invoking the program is structured and efficient:**

- No additional process to invoke, no shell syntax to interpret
- Clearly defined inputs, no issues with special characters
- Always works the same across platforms where the program is installed.

**Invoking a shell to invoke the program is flexible and convenient:**

- Allows doing shell things like

  - Globs: `ls *.wav`
  - Pipes: `ls | wc -l`
  - Redirections: `ls > file`
  - Various forms of expansions: `ls "$HOME"`

However, it requires great care when dealing with user input, otherwise it will not be able to handle special characters in file names, and may allow arbitrary code execution. It may also handle commands differently depending on the shell `sh` refers to (such as `bash` vs `dash`).

---

Books and references may use a shell because instead of explaining how the UNIX process model works in terms of syscall and what is and isn't handled by the shell, they can just say "copy-paste the command from your terminal".

Whenever possible, you should use direct invocation.